# How to merge two php codes with some condition?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website in which I am controlling the content of homepage through the following code:

**Code A:**

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
]);
```

Through above code, 4 posts are displayed on the homepage.

In some condition, I want it to be displayed 2. When `if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3)`, I want posts_per_page to be **2**. For that, I use the following logic:

**Code B:**

```
if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3) {
$special_reports = new \WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
]);
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering, if there is any way we can merge Code A and Code B with the `($data->{"toggle_status"}==3)` logic as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the ternary operator

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_status"} == 3 ? 2 : 4,
]);
```

Comment: Might be good to link to the [ternary documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), because new programmers sometimes have a hard time grasping the concept.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a variable that you set based on your condition.

```
$posts_per_page = 4; //default is set to 4
if($data->toggle_status === 3) {
    $posts_per_page = 2; //set to 2 if condition is met
}

$special_reports = new \WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
]);
```

This has the added benefit of being able to easily add more conditions later to change the value in the end.

Note: If `$data->toggle_status` returns a string, your if statement here may change slightly, it would become either:

- `$data->toggle_status === "3"`
- `$data->toggle_status == 3`

Comment: Hope `toggle_status` isn't a string ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver From OP's code, I don't understand why they were using the complex syntax, it essentially would call it the same way as in my code right?

Comment: I meant, if `$data->toggle_status = '3'` :-) Then `===` is a nogo.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah I know, I updated my answer to address this. I was just trying to confirm the other thing for my own sanity :)

Answer (score 2):

Just define the array and then add to or change the array:

```
$array = [
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4];

if($data->toggle_status == 3) {
    $array['posts_per_page'] = 2;
}

$special_reports = new \WP_Query($array);
```

There are multiple ways, but you get the idea.  You could also use a `switch`, or if you always want to show one less then:

```
$array['posts_per_page'] = $data->toggle_status - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes easily

```
$param = [
            'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
            'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        ];

if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3) {
    $param[ 'posts_per_page' ] = 3;
} else {
    $param[ 'posts_per_page' ] = 4;
}

$special_reports = new \WP_Query(  $param );
```